# Bash command inside python throwing syntax error

Tags: python, bash

I am running `openssl` command to create a self signed certificate inside Python script.
Facing Unexpected "(" syntax error.

```
import os

os.system('openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 7300 -nodes -keyout istio_gw.key -out istio_gw.crt -subj "/CN=csd.nokia.com/O=Nokia" -extensions san -config <( echo "[req]"; echo"distinguished_name=req";)')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bashism, so you need to prepend it with `bash -c`:

```py
shell_command = 'openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 7300 -nodes -keyout istio_gw.key -out istio_gw.crt -subj "/CN=csd.nokia.com/O=Nokia" -extensions san -config <( echo "[req]"; echo"distinguished_name=req";)'

os.system("bash -c '{}'".format(shell_command))
```

But more importantly, you should be using `subprocess` instead of `os.system`

To use `subprocess`, you should be able to use the `shell=True` argument:

```py
subprocess.check_output(shell_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

With SubProcess :

import subprocess

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

shell_command = 'openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 7300 -nodes -keyout istio_gw.key -out istio_gw.crt -subj "/CN=csd.nokia.com/O=Nokia" -extensions san -config <( echo "[req]"; echo "distinguished_name=req"; echo "[san]"; echo "subjectAltName=DNS:*.nokia.com")'

p = Popen("bash -c '{}'".format(shell_command), shell=True, bufsize=-1, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

out,err = p.communicate()

print(out)

print(err)

Comment: I'm not sure you need to use both `bash -c` and `shell=True`, see my edited answer